# Find lines where column starts with a string

Tags: bash

I need to find lines in the text file where the second column starts with the number `117`. How do I do that in bash? I tried

```
grep -E 117 test.txt
```

but that just prints everything with `117`.

Comment: Use `awk '$2 ~ /^117/' file`

Comment: What's your field separator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` is not the right tool for this. Use one of these 2 awk solutions:

```bash
# regex approach
awk '$2 ~ /^117/' test.txt

# non-regex approach
awk 'index($2, "117") == 1' test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use [grep](/questions/tagged/grep), make sure that you match the second column:

```
grep -E '^\w+\s+117' test.txt
```

- `-E` use extended regular expressions
- `^` start of the line anchor
- `\w+` one or more characters
- `\s+` one or more whitespaces
- `117` match when the second column starts with the number 117